# jsp pass object to an include

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Currently I am having a page with a small content need to be refreshed frequently.

For example: 
The jsp content is

```
  Chapter 1 :

  section abc:

  section def:

  section ghi:
```

Assuming I have a class Chapter and its sections are parameters in it

```
 class Chapter{
     Section abc;
     Section def;
     Section ghi;
 }
```

I am using spring mvc, I am adding the following models

```
model.addAttribute("chapter", chapter);
model.addAttribute("abc", chapter.getAbc());
model.addAttribute("def", chapter.getDef());
model.addAttribute("ghi", chapter.getGhi());
```

While calling the main page initially I can load the individual sections by using the jsp:includes , while updating them independently I shall add that particular model to that particular jsp page and update it using ajax. 
This works fine.

But

The question is, 
How can I change the design so that can I manage the whole with just

```
model.addAttribute("chapter", chapter);
```

so that I can use the chapter object to get the abc,def,ghi values instead of explicitly passing them .

The problem is I am not able to pass the individual objects to the included jsps from the chapter object like ..

```
<jsp:include page="abc.jsp" >
     <jsp:param name="abc" value="${ chapter.abc}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

this is not possible. as I can pass only strings

small problem , long description .. hope I made my point.

Comment: small problem, long description, where was the question?

Comment: "hope I made my point" - not even close, no.  Your long description doesn't have a question in it.

Comment: extremely sorry for not reading even once before posting it,was in a hurry ...

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that you can only pass String parameters to jsp:include.  Too bad you can't pass objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass Strings as request parameters, but you can set any kind of object as request *attributes*. Request scope (not page scope) beans should also work.